# Is it good practice to use Array.flat()?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a function that takes in an Array, iterates over it finding all Objects and displays them.

In rare cases, I have to supply an Object which is not an Array by default and hence my function fails to iterate over it and display.

Array looks like:

```
const array = [
  { "name" : "foo"},
  { "name" : "bar"},
  { "name" : "baz"}
]
```

and this works. However, sometimes the data I get could be this:

```
const array = { "name" : "List"}
```

So far i tried using :

```
[array].flat()
```

It as i wrap the array with [] and us flat - it gives what i expect !

Is this correct approach ?

Comment: I don't see why not. Alternatively you can do `Array.isArray(array) ? array : [array]`, it's probably faster but much verbose

Comment: It largely depends on your use case, in general it's probably fine to normalize the data to an array if it could be either.

Comment: Yes, to normalize to an array using flat is good ? or Array.isArray is good ? @EvanTrimboli

Comment: The ternary is better since it only wraps  when needed

Comment: Upvotes for errbody

Comment: Is i tried that too - its working as same ! But which is best ? or is there any community convention ?

Comment: Your own solution is more concise!

Comment: It has the same outcome but is NOT working the same. It is much faster to NOT wrap and flat if not needed

Comment: If less than a large number of entries, then go with the more readable `[array].flat()` however it is VERY clear to the reader what you are doing if you have the ternary

Comment: It has entries around 15 and sometimes 20 ( and the data has nested arrays and sometimes object also ) ! @mplungjan

Comment: I'd personally go with `[].concat(array)` but I'm just used to using this construct from before `.flat()` was available. It still the same thing - it normalises the data to an array in either case.

Comment: Will that helps on performance ? Whats the key difference using concat ?

Comment: With 20 entries, whatever method you choose will be for readability rather than performance

Comment: Ya thats why choosed the onelined - flat lol ! @mplungjan

Comment: However  `Array.isArray(array) ? array : [array]` is self-explaining

Comment: @samanthas there isn't much of a difference. It's just that `.flat()` is more recent and `[].concat(arr)` is the same operation as `[arr].flat()` but the latter wasn't available before.

Comment: Understood thanks ! @VLAZ

Comment: Yes right ! Thanks for the suggestions ! @mplungjan